# Update the view of my JavaFX app while it is executing an external process

Tags: java, javafx, processbuilder

I have a problem to update the view of my JavaFX app while it is executing an external process. In the code below, into the `while`, I put some code to display the status of the executed process.

The `System.out.println(line);` works perfectly, and I see the output of the process in the console.

But the `tStatus.setText(line);` has no effect

The `refreshListFilesDestination()` neither

Someone has an idea of what I do wrong?

Thanks

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
      "cmd.exe", "/c", "java -jar \"c:\\Program Files (x86)\\JSignPdf\\JSignPdf.jar\" -kst WINDOWS-MY " + stringFilesList + " -d " + fieldDirectoryDestination.getText() + " -V");

builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
try {
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(line); // this work fine I see all the outpout comming in the console
        tStatus.setText(line); // Don't work, except at the very end
        refreshListFilesDestination(); // This is a method who refresh a list of files, it Don't work
    }
} catch (Exception e1) {
    tStatus.setText("Command return an error");
}
```

Comment: You need more context here in order for people to help. It seems that you are running this code on the FX Application Thread? Ideally you should post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

JavaFx doesn't know about the changes you've done. It's better to bind, something like that:

```
tStatus.textProperty().bind(line)
```

In your case, it may be needed to change the variable for the textfield (make it in a class where you define the `textfield` and make it settable), then it should work when you just make `classWhereTextField.setTextFieldText(line)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```java
    tStatus.setText(line);
```

to

```java
    Platform.runLater(() -> tStatus.setText(line));
```

or

```java
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tStatus.setText(line);
        }
    });
```

[see more about method runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks, but your code make an error : "java: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final"   ...'line' can't be final besause it is populated by line = r.readLine();

Comment: Try second variant without lambda expression.